# Flutter GridView Widget for Smaller Screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-gridview

I am trying to build a 2x3 GridView in my app, it works quite fine on big screen devices but for devices like iPhone SE (4 inch) GridView is not scaling it self. It appears with scroll or overflows from the bottom.

How can I make sure, all the other widgets are placed to their positions and rest of the space is used by GridView and without scroll, every item is visible? You can check the code below or also can check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/btutal/pen/RwWxRNB)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 static const String id = 'stats_screen';

 StatsScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 _StatsScreenState createState() => _StatsScreenState();
}

class _StatsScreenState extends State<StatsScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Container(
       padding:
           EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 0.0),
       child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
         children: <Widget>[
           Text(
             'MyText',
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
           ),
           SizedBox(
             height: 20,
           ),
           Expanded(
             child: GridView.count(
               primary: false,
               shrinkWrap: true,
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
               crossAxisSpacing: 10,
               mainAxisSpacing: 10,
               crossAxisCount: 2,
               children: <Widget>[
                 Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                   child: const Text('He\'d have you all unravel at the'),
                   color: Colors.teal[100],
                 ),
                 Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                   child: const Text('Heed not the rabble'),
                   color: Colors.teal[200],
                 ),
                 Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                   child: const Text('Sound of screams but the'),
                   color: Colors.teal[300],
                 ),
                 Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                   child: const Text('Who scream'),
                   color: Colors.teal[400],
                 ),
                 Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                   child: const Text('Revolution is coming...'),
                   color: Colors.teal[500],
                 ),
                 Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                   child: const Text('Revolution, they...'),
                   color: Colors.teal[600],
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
           SizedBox(
             height: 30.0,
           ),
           RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () {},
             child: Text(
               'MyRaisedButton',
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 30.0,
                 color: Colors.white,
               ),
             ),
             color: Colors.red[900],
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
             ),
           )
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridView.count` has a property called `childAspectRatio`.

`childAspectRatio` is the ratio of the cross-axis to the main-axis extent of each child.

You can adjust the properties starting from `0` to any value to your desired app requirement.

I hope this helps.

NOTE: The `childAspectRatio` must have a value greater than `0`.

Check the code below for an example:

```
GridView.count(
               childAspectRatio: 1.0,
               primary: false,
               shrinkWrap: true,
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
               crossAxisSpacing: 10,
               mainAxisSpacing: 10,
               crossAxisCount: 2,
               children: <Widget>[
                  ........
                   ]
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrap the body in a SafeArea Widget.

Comment: Thnaks, I've  tried that. Nothing overflows but GridView has an active scroll, some items are not visible.